# JavaFx CSS TableView change opacity only texts

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview

I need to change only table-view only 1 column's texts opacity.

```
#column_2 {
-fx-opacity: 60%
}
.table-cell {
    -fx-border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
    -fx-opacity: 100%;
}
```

There #column_2 in tableView's column id.
I tried this, but this changed border opacity too.

So how do I change only column text opacity? (without change border opacity)

[look in image right column, when I do opacity 60%, this changes border opacity too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS5mu.png)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```css
.table-row-cell #column_2 {
    -fx-opacity: 60%;
}

.table-row-cell {
    -fx-border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
}
```